# WebClient - Flux<DataBuffer> - Content not getting created

Tags: spring-webclient

I am  trying to download a file form remote  location using Spring WebClient and when I does that , the file is getting created but the content is not getting created. The File still remain 0KB. Any help ,

```
     Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer =  emailTemplateWebclient
            .get()
            .uri(gitHubEmailTemplateURL + fileName + ".html")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);

    dataBuffer.subscribe();
    DataBufferUtils
            .write(dataBuffer, destination, StandardOpenOption.CREATE).block();
```